# Unable to animate button

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4, xcode9

I'm having some issue animating the button "StartButton", it does not pulsate.

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var StartButton: UIButton!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    playVideo()
    self.StartButton.pulsate()
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 6.3) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Whenever I remove the "playVideo()" function everything goes back to normal and the button starts pulsating again. How can I fix this?
Here is the code for the "playVideo()"

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "My Movie 1", ofType: "mp4")
    {
        let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
        let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerController.player = player

        present(playerController, animated: true, completion: {
            player.play()
        })
        playerController.showsPlaybackControls = false
    }
```

Comment: Add the code for playVideo().

Comment: in playVideo function `presenting` `playerController`, it covers current controllers, present your playerController after animating `StartButton` to overcome this.

Comment: But I want the StartButton to animate after the video is dismissed.